# dataframe iloc works unexpectedly in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am creating a dataframe like this.

```
np.random.seed(2)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,6,(6,6)))

out[]

0   1   1   4   3   4   1
1   3   2   4   3   5   5
2   5   4   5   3   4   4
3   3   2   3   5   4   1
4   5   4   2   3   1   5
5   5   3   5   3   2   1
```

spliting the dataframe into 3,3 matrix like below, it will have 16 matrix.
    dfs=[]

```
for col in range(df.shape[1]-2):
    for row in range(df.shape[0]-2):
        dfs.append(df.iloc[row:row+3,col:col+3])
```

lets print,

```
dfs[0]
1   1   4
3   2   4
5   4   5

dfs[1]
3   2   4
5   4   5
3   2   3
.
.
.
dfs[15]

5   4   1
3   1   5
3   2   1
```

writing a function to change the values from each matrix in locations [1,0] and [1,2] to zero,
so that my output will looks like,

```
dfs[0]
1   1   4
0   2   0
5   4   5


def process(x):
    new=[]
    for d in x:
        d.iloc[1,0]=0
        d.iloc[1,2]=0
        new.append(d)
        print(d)
    return new

dfs=process(dfs.copy())
```

my expected output, is

```
dfs[0]
1   1   4
0   2   0
5   4   5
```

but what my function returns is,

```
dfs[0]
1   1   4
0   0   0
0   0   0

dfs[1]
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

It producres more zeros in all matrix. I don't know why it is working unexpectedly or what I am doing wrong with my function `process` please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, you are a victim of [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters), which can [lead to bad things happening](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

When you slice the original `DataFrame`, you get overlapping views.

Modifying one changes the others too, since the second row of one chunk is the first row of another, and the third row of the first chunk is the first row of yet another, and so on...which is why you see non-zero values only at the "edges", since those are unique to a single chunk.

You can make copies of each slice, like this:

```
def process(x):
    new = []
    for d in x:
        d = d.copy()  # each one is now a copy
        d.iloc[1, 0]=0
        d.iloc[1, 2]=0
        new.append(d)
    return new
```

Lastly, note that `dfs = process(dfs)` is actually fine; you don't need to make a copy of the enclosing `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code and `process` function call to get your required output. Also, I used copy in for loop to make subset of dataframe which is independent to change in future, in your case it makes changes to original df which are reflected with all zeros in other dfs list:

```
for col in range(df.shape[1]-2):
    for row in range(df.shape[0]-2):
        dfs.append(df.iloc[row:row+3,col:col+3].copy())

dfs=process(dfs)
```